# HttpListener HTTP error 400

Tags: c#, java, android, http

I am using the `HttpListener` to implement a simple HTTP protocol for my connection service. When I connect with a browser to it, it works fine, but if I use Android's `DefaultHttpClient`, I get a "400 Bad Request".

C# code:

```
httpListener = new HttpListener();
httpListener.Prefixes.Add(String.Format("http://*:{0}/", port));
httpListener.Start();
```

Java code:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(path);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpHost httphost = new HttpHost(host, port);

StringEntity body = new StringEntity("Stuff I post", "UTF-8");
body.setContentType("text/xml");
post.setEntity(body);

response = client.execute(httphost, post);
StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
```

Nowhere can I find out what exactly goes wrong, all I get is "400 Bad Request". When I look at the POST by listening to a simple port, what I see looks OK.

Frustrating thing is that it worked a few days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I have to start my path with `/`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the server is expecting XML (judging by "text/xml") and you are sending plain text so the APPLICATION on the server is complaining with "400 Bad Request", i.e. it is unable to parse the XML. Try to send XML in format expected by the server, or even beter try to send the above request to test page, like some simple PHP with `<?php var_dump($_POST);` in it. If the test page returns 200 OK then the request is working as expected and you will have to work your way through XML format expected by the server.

Comment: It doesn't even get there. It's the `HttpListener` that is throwing the 400. Turned out I was missing a leading `/` in my path.